# hash with values as Hash or Array Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to group certain set of records but most likely doing it inefficiently. Need help -

First I have following set of data collected from bunch of files processed - 
      
BookA - section1, section2
      BookB - section2, section4

I used hh = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = {}} and stored it as  -

```
hh[BookA][section1] = BookA
hh[BookA][section2] = BookA
hh[BookB][section2] = BookB
hh[BookB][section4] = BookB
```

But i need to print all this as following - 
    
section1 - BookA
    
section2 - BookA
    
section2 - BookB
    
section4 - BookB

Any suggestions how to do this ....

So I created 
h = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}
section_hash = Hash.new([])
Iterating - 
h.each do |k,v|
v.each do |s|
puts "#{s} - #{k}"
fh[s] << k
end
end
puts fh
It prints everything correctly but fh is nil, any idea what's wrong....
output from puts command 
s1 - b1
s2 - b1
s2 - b2

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. You are trying to... group together all the books for any given section? Then print them out in section-order?

Comment: Thats correct Taryn. Reading bunch of files that have book and all its sections. And finally need to print for each section what all books have that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it by using the section as the hash-key like this:

```
# so this will create a new empty array for any keys we add
section_hash = Hash.new([])

# you can grab out the lines of the file or use each to do it line by line.
book_lines = File.readlines("my_file.txt")

# now go through each of these and add the data into the hash
book_lines.each do |line|

  # convert each line to a key/value pair
  # eg "BookA - section1, section2"
  # {"BookA" => ["section1", "secton2"]}
  book, sections = line.split(" - ")
  sections = sections.split(', ')    

  # and hash away these values
  sections.each do |section|
     section_hash[section] << book
  end
end
```

then you can print with:

```
section_hash.each do |section, books|
  # you may choose to uniq (in case of double ups)
  books.uniq.each do |book|
    puts "#{section} - #{book}"
  end
end
```